# How can I optimize my PostgreSQL database for read-heavy workloads?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have a PostgreSQL database that is primarily used for read operations, with occasional writes. However, I'm experiencing slow query performance and high CPU usage.

```
# Install pgBouncer
sudo apt-get install -y pgBouncer

# Edit the configuration file
sudo nano /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini

# Add the following configuration:
[databases]
mydb = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = trust
```

I tried using this, but I am unsure where I am making a mistake.

What are some best practices for optimizing a PostgreSQL database for read-heavy workloads? Are there any specific configuration settings or indexing strategies that I should consider? What are some common pitfalls to avoid?

Comment: Explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for all your SQL statements is your best friend. Without it, you’re blind

Comment: And use `pg_stat_statements` to identify your problem statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as indexing goes, you should use indexes on the columns that are most frequently used, but don't overdo it. Also there are some configurations for postgres about memory usage, parallel workers etc. that you might want to look into.

Having good knowledge on how to construct queries also help with the performance. For example don't  always use `SELECT *` as this will fetch all the columns for a table and you might not need all of them. Also don't forget to regularly use the `VACUUM` mechanism of postgres to clear your database of unnecessary objects.

Comment: Why would you use VACUUM manually when autovacuum is running? And SELECT * is always a bad idea because you don't know what you will get. And what's the definition of "overdo" ? Especially in a read-heavy workload you don't have the overhead of writing an index. And when the indexes make your reads faster, it works. And when an index isn't used, you can drop it. Just check the statistics. But without many writes, who cares? Storage is cheap.